# Can I use a Esri geocoding service with my custom basemap?

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geocoding

I am looking at the JavaScript samples in [here](http://www.arcgis.com/apps/SocialMedia/index.html?appid=8295e698fead4f8e850c40e1ab327c54). I am searching some street by search bar. But not zooming to street, it only viewing city. I have a custom tiled map service layer in my server. Can I use [this](http://www.arcgis.com/apps/SocialMedia/index.html?appid=8295e698fead4f8e850c40e1ab327c54) geocoding service and my custom basemap?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the free Esri service on any map, but you can't do batch geocoding (requires a subscription). If you are not using the 102100 standard web mapping projection for your custom tiles, you can ask for a different projection from the service.

Documentation
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-online-geocoding-rest-api/#/Overview_of_the_World_Geocoding_Service/02q000000008000000/

Example
http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?text=380+New+York+Street%2C+Redlands%2C+CA+92373&f=pjson